# Why is my SQL LEFT JOIN query not working?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to perform some summarizing actions on two different tables and then join them in a single query, but I keep getting the "Syntax error in JOIN operation"

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
SELECT [Payment File - Q4].[Accident Number] AS [Accident Number],
  Count([Payment File - Q4].[Accident Number]) AS [Q4 Count],
  Sum([Payment File - Q4].[PI Amount]) AS [Q4 SumOfPI Amount],
  Sum([Payment File - Q4].[PD Amount]) AS [Q4 SumOfPD Amount]
FROM [Payment File - Q4] AS [Q4]
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT [Payment File - Q2].[Accident Number] AS [Accident Number],
    Count([Payment File - Q2].[Accident Number]) AS [Q2 Count],
    Sum([Payment File - Q2].[PI Amount]) AS [Q2 SumOfPI Amount],
    Sum([Payment File - Q2].[PD Amount]) AS [Q2 SumOfPD Amount]
  FROM [Payment File - Q2]
  WHERE ((([Payment File - Q2].[Input Date]) < #1/7/2019#))
  GROUP BY [Payment File - Q2].[Accident Number]
) AS [Q2]
  ON [Q2].[Accident Number] = [Q4].[Accident Number]
WHERE ((([Payment File - Q4].[Input Date]) < #1/7/2019#))
GROUP BY [Q4].[Accident Number];
```

Comment: (1) Your query makes no sense.  Why are you using `LEFT JOIN` but using no columns from the second table?  (2) The `LEFT JOIN` is going to throw off the aggregation values.  Even if you get this query working, it won't do any useful, as far as I can tell.

Comment: you are calculating sum and count without grouping them. thats why you are getting error. but as @GordonLinoff says, what is purpose of the join?

Comment: I didnt expect to get responses so quickly, so thanks for that. 
I am trying to do sum and count two different datasets at two different points to compare the two.

I have updated the code in the question. Does this make more sense? Thank you.

Comment: you should also keep in mind that this query only shows q4 data and also in intersection records. you cant see records which is only in q2

Answer (score 1):

I 100% agree with Gordon's comment, to get this working you'll need to do the following:

1. Your subquery makes use of aggregation functions `Sum()` and `Count()` therefore it will need to contain a GROUP BY. In other words your subquery must be able to run and produce a result set all on its own. Right now it will just error due to the lack of a `GROUP BY` clause.
2. Your subquery needs an alias. You can't just reference the table name again in the main query as that table is out of context (it only can be referenced inside the same SQL/subquery where it is contained in the `FROM` clause).
3. You will need to put your Q4 stuff inside of its own subquery. Otherwise you will being doing a Many:1 join. Both tables need to be aggregated at the `[Accident Number]` level BEFORE being joined otherwise you risk artificially inflating your `sum()` and `count()` because they will be performed AFTER the join.
4. You will need to add the columns from your subquery into your main query otherwise it's pointless to JOIN it in.

Consider this rewrite:

```
SELECT Q4.[Accident Number],
       [Q4 Count],
       [Q4 SumOfPI Amount],
       [Q4 SumOfPD Amount],
       [Q2 Count],
       [Q2 SumOfPI Amount],
       [Q2 SumOfPD Amount]
FROM
(
SELECT [Payment File - Q4].[Accident Number] AS [Accident Number],
       Count([Payment File - Q4].[Accident Number]) AS [Q4 Count],
       Sum([Payment File - Q4].[PI Amount]) AS [Q4 SumOfPI Amount],
       Sum([Payment File - Q4].[PD Amount]) AS [Q4 SumOfPD Amount]
FROM [Payment File - Q4].[Accident Number]
GROUP BY [Payment File - Q4].[Accident Number]
WHERE (((Q4.[Input Date])<#1/7/2019#))
) AS Q4
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT [Payment File - Q2].[Accident Number] AS [Accident Number],
       Count([Payment File - Q2].[Accident Number]) AS [Q2 Count],
       Sum([Payment File - Q2].[PI Amount]) AS [Q2 SumOfPI Amount],
       Sum([Payment File - Q2].[PD Amount]) AS [Q2 SumOfPD Amount]
FROM [Payment File - Q2].[Accident Number]
GROUP BY [Payment File - Q2].[Accident Number]
) AS Q2
ON Q2.[Accident Number]=Q4.[Accident Number]
```

So now what this is doing is getting all accident records from your Q4 table and restricting the records for < January 7th 2019 from that table. It then sums up your PI and PD for each accident number in Q4. Next it heads to Q2 table and grabs every distinct Accident number and sums up it's PI and PD. Then it takes the Q4 accident numbers and searches the summed up Q2 accident numbers for a match. It displays all of the summed up Q4 (< January 7th 2019) accident numbers and any of the matching accident numbers it found from the summed up Q2 accident numbers.

That may or may not be what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone. I edited JNevill's query and it now works. Thanks also for the explanation - much appreciated!